# JS module exports aren't working with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to setup `Jest` on a `Node.js` environment. Following is a function defined in a file named `controllers/a.js`:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

module.exports = sum;
```

This is accessed from the `tests.js` file:

```
const sum = require('../controllers/a');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

This works fine:

```
 PASS  tests/tests.js
  √ adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 (5 ms)
```

However, if I modify `a.js` as follows:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

exports.sum = sum;
```

then I get `TypeError`:

```
 FAIL  tests/tests.js
  × adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 (3 ms)

  ● adds 1 + 2 to equal 3

    TypeError: sum is not a function

      2 |
      3 | test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    > 4 |     expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
        |            ^
      5 | });
```

Tried the following ways to export, all failed with the `TypeError` above:

- `module.exports.sum = sum;`
- `module.exports = { sum: sum };`
- `exports = sum;`
- `exports = { sum: sum };`

I need to export multiple functions for testing in `Jest`. How can I do that if `Jest` doesn't recognize `module.exports` as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```js
function sum() { ... }
exports.sum = sum;
```

and in your test:

```js
const { sum } = require('../controllers/a');
```

Because when you import your file in your test you need to look inside the object returned by require() to find the correct function (here sum).

Answer (score 2):

if you do `exports.sum = sum;`

You need to import it like: `const {sum} = require('../controllers/a');`